# Running Prezto inside a shell session on Emacs

Tags: emacs, prezto

I'm trying to run a [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) terminal session from Emacs, but when I execute `M-shell`, a normal ZSH gets loaded. How can I get prezto configuration to kick in?

Also, how to avoid `Completions` buffer appearing and instead get autocomplete to execute like it does with ZSH or Prezto? For example, if you type a folder name partially and you hit `TAB`, different folder names get autocompleted when running with ZSH + Presto in command line. But, in my current set up on Emacs, instead of autocompleting folder names, it opens a new buffer with completions suggestions which sucks.

**UPDATE**: I've found an alternative way to start the ZSH shell, by executing `M-x ansi-term` then select `bin/zsh` and that seems to start a normal ZSH with Prezto and all the expected autocompletion. Is that the right way?

Answer (score 0):

`M-x shell` creates an Emacs shell, to get Prezto, you need to run the terminal emulator, with `M-x ansi-term`. More information on the difference between them two [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview).